# How do i assert that a unit tested method return True?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

This is my Domain class

```
public partial class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string DepartmentFullName { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC application, this is how my `DepartmentService` class looks like.

```
public class DepartmentService : IDepartmentService
{
    private IUnitOfWork _UoW;
    private IRepository<Department> repository;
    public DepartmentService(IUnitOfWork UoW)
    {
        _UoW = UoW;
        repository = _UoW.GetRepository<Department>();
    }

    public IList<Department> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }

    public bool SaveDepartment(Department newDepartment)
    {
        try
        {
            repository.Add(newDepartment);
            _UoW.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I wrote one unit test for GetAllDepartments methods as below.

```
[Test]
public void When_GetAllDepartments_Is_Called_RepositoryGetAll_ShouldBeCalled()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Department>())
                  .Returns(mockRepository.Object);
    var sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

    // Act
    sut.GetAllDepartments();

    // Assert
    mockRepository.Verify(x => x.GetAll());
}
```

I want to test the `SaveDepartment` method where, when department is saved successfully, it should return true. I am not able to write unit test for this.

I also want to test when DepartmentCode or DepartmentFullName is blank and if Save is attempted, an exception should be thrown.

This is what i have so far.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSucessfully_SaveNewDepartment()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();
    Department newDept = new Department { 
          CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
          Status = true, 
          DepartmentFullName = "DFN", 
          DepartmentCode = "DC" };
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Department>())
                  .Returns(mockRepository.Object);
    var sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

    // Act
    sut.SaveDepartment(newDept);

    // Assert 
    // ???
}
```

Comment: `bool result = sut.SaveDepartment(newDept); Assert.IsTrue(result);`?

Comment: Won't  sut.SaveDepartment(newDept); actually add a record in DB ? I think i dont want this to happen. Or should it happen in unit testing ?

Comment: you instructed the mock unitofwork to return you a mock repository. Such repository won't act on the database

Comment: Have updated the OP. How do i test for failure ? Because if DepartmentCode or FullName is missing then exception should be thrown.

Comment: @Nexus: Sorry, could you mark as Answer if you're satisfied by any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - move all common arrange code to SetUp method:

```
private Mock<IUnitOfWork> mockUnitOfWork;
private Mock<IRepository<Department>> mockRepository;
private DepartmentService sut;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Department>())
                  .Returns(mockRepository.Object);
    sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
}

// tests will be here
```

That will make tests much easier to read and maintain. Next - do not stick to implementation when naming your tests:

```
When_GetAllDepartments_Is_Called_RepositoryGetAll_ShouldBeCalled
```

What if you will rename repository method to FindAll? What if service method will be renamed? Test becomes obsolete. And nobody will know about that. You should describe WHAT your SUT should do instead of HOW:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldGetAllDepartments()
{
    var expected = new List<Department>{ CreateDepartment(), CreateDepartment()};
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetAll()).Returns(expected);
    var actual = sut.GetAllDepartments();
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
}
```

As you can see, test name changed. Also I verify different things here - not only repository was called (that check can be removed actually), but that service returns exactly same departments which it gets from repository. Thats what service does. And second test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSucessfullySaveNewDepartment()
{
    var department = CreateDepartment();
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.Add(department));
    var result = sut.SaveDepartment(department);
    Assert.True(result);
    mockRepository.VerifyAll();
    mockUnitOfWork.Verify(u => u.Save());
}
```

It verifies following service behavior: service should pass to repository exactly same department instance which was passed to service, and it should return true, it also calls save on unit of work to submit data.

BTW As you can see above I use helper method to make tests more clean:

```
private Department CreateDepartment()
{
    return new Department { 
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, 
        Status = true, 
        DepartmentFullName = "DFN", 
        DepartmentCode = "DC" 
    };
}
```

---

And bonus - verifying that service does not saves department which already exists:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotSaveExistingDepartment()
{
    mockUnitOfWork.Setup(u => u.Save()).Throws<NonUniqueEntityException>();
    var result = sut.SaveDepartment(CreateDepartment());
    Assert.False(result);
    mockUnitOfWork.VerifyAll();
}
```

As you can see, expected behavior is simple - when unit of work throws NonUniqueEntityException during department saving, service should return false. Yes, I think it's better to return false. Here is service code which makes this test pass:

```
public bool SaveDepartment(Department department)
{
    try
    {
        repository.Add(department);
        _UoW.Save();
        return true;
    }
    catch (NonUniqueEntityException e)
    {
        // log exception
        return false;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the redundant try...catch.
There's no point in catching an exception just to rethrow it.
As far as the test you asked for here is the snippet:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldSucessfully_SaveNewDepartment()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();
        Department newDept = new Department { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, Status = true, DepartmentFullName = "DFN", DepartmentCode = "DC" };
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Department>()).Returns(mockRepository.Object);

        var sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        // Act
        bool result = sut.SaveDepartment(newDept);

        // Assert 
        Assert.That(result, Is.True);
    }

   [Test]
    public void ShouldThrowExceptionWhenExceptionThrownInternally_SaveNewDepartment()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Department>>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.GetRepository<Department>()).Returns(mockRepository.Object);
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Save()).Throws<Exception>();

        var sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        // Act
        TestDelegate action = () => sut.SaveDepartment(new Department());

        // Assert 
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(action);
    }
```

> I also want to test when DepartmentCode or DepartmentFullName is blank and if Save is attempted, an exception should be thrown.

It depend on who you expect to check for those values: if you want to rely on you database or unitofwork to check for those fields this is not the fixture to test for specific failure conditions it you want a unit test. Here you should only test what happens in case uow throws exception.

If you plan to add those check in the department service than you can do the following:

```
[Test]
    public void ShouldThrowExceptionWhenDepartmentCodeIsNull_SaveNewDepartment()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        Department newDept = new Department
                                 {
                                     CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, 
                                     Status = true, DepartmentFullName = "DFN", 
                                     DepartmentCode = null
                                 };

        var sut = new DepartmentService(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        // Act
        TestDelegate action = () => sut.SaveDepartment(newDept);

        // Assert 
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(action);
    }
```

provided that you modified your method as follows:

```
public bool SaveDepartment(Department newDepartment)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newDepartment.DepartmentCode))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("DepartmentCode must be not null");
        }

        repository.Add(newDepartment);
        _UoW.Save();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have not understood why we need this line of code.mockUnitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Save()).Throws<Exception>(); Exception should only be thrown when DepartmentCode  or DepartmentFullName is blank. In your code, object newDept has all of its properties set properly.

Comment: If you expect your uow.Save() method to fail somehow you should test the expected behavior when that method fails, no matter the reason. In that particular case it's cleare to not set the properties at all in the test. I 'll edit the example. But the important thing is that if you plan to explicitly test the values in SaveDepartment you should follow the last Fixture method I wrote. If you plan to rely on database to check for null values you should add an integration test on the uow and repository together.